# where does qtcreator with cmake store run and build settings, and how to set via script?

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator, nfs

In my usage at least, I sometimes delete my CMake build folder and create a new one, or have multiple build folders (one per computer) but only one source folder (nfs mount).

From what I can tell, QT Creator saves settings into CMakeLists.txt.user  *inside the source* tree, and some others settings into the 'project.cbp' file in the build folder. If I set settings from the GUI, they are lost after wipe/create build folder. Fair enough, but I'd like to use a script to set them up again when a new build is made.

So, how do I:

a) make QT Creator write the CMakeLists.txt.user folder somewhere other than the source tree so that machine-specific settings are kept (e.g. debug on the development computer, release on the test computer) ?

b) read/write the build and run settings from QT Creator project, such as debug arguments for each executable and extra build commands (e.g. -j8) ?

Then I would do something like "execute_process( ... )" in CMakeLists.txt to set some debug and build arguments for the QT Creator project.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, actually the command args, build settings, and related items are set in the CMakeLists.txt.user from QTCreator...

for example:

```
<valuemap key="ProjectExplorer.Target.RunConfiguration.1" type="QVariantMap">
<value key="CMakeProjectManager.BaseEnvironmentBase" type="int">2</value>
<value key="CMakeProjectManager.CMakeRunConfiguation.Title" type="QString">matching_test</value>
<value key="CMakeProjectManager.CMakeRunConfiguration.Arguments" type="QString">camera.pklogitech.yml  0   .</value>
```

so the args that are used are  " camera.pklogitech.yml   0   .  "  for this binary's entry...

So I guess a script could be made to go in and set those values by default... too bad QT Creator doesn't provide a nicer interface to import them.